# How to aggregate different word files using VBA-excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an amount of word files that I would like to aggregate into a single file. For that I use a table in Excel to select which of my files I would like to aggregate. I have written the code in Excel since I would like the word files not to contain macros.

I have succeded in opening, copying and pasting in the aggregate file, however the pasting always delete the previous content. This means that I only end-up with the content of the last copied word file. I believe what I need is to indicate that the pasting should occur at the end of the file, but have unfortunately not been able to succeed yet.

```
    'copy the text in the Service Document
    ServiceDoc.Activate
    ServiceDoc.Range.Copy
    'Paste into the aggregate document
    MainDoc.Activate
    MainDoc.Range.MoveEnd
    MainDoc.Range.Paste
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
With MainDoc
    .Activate
    .Content.Select 
    .Application.Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Application.Selection.Paste
End With
```